# error while drawing rectangle on detected qr code

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

i created a simple program that detects qr code on image :

```
self.qrReader=cv2.QRCodeDetector()
self.text,points,_=self.qrReader.detectAndDecode(self.img)
```

now when im drawing rectangle on detected qr code :

```
cv2.rectangle(self.img,points[0][0],points[0][2],color,thickness)
```

im getting an error :

```
  File "e:\Users\Abhimanyu\Documents\aiocv\aiocv\qr_code_reader_module.py", line 19, in findQRCode
    cv2.rectangle(self.img,points[0][0],points[0][2],color,thickness)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
>  - Can't parse 'rec'. Expected sequence length 4, got 2
>  - Can't parse 'rec'. Expected sequence length 4, got 2
```

when im printing points[0][0] :

```
[ 40.       40.     ]
```

and when im printing points[0][2] :

```
[288.99997 288.99997]
```

the complete array looks like this :

```
[[[ 40.       40.     ]
  [288.99997  40.     ]
  [288.99997 288.99997]
  [ 40.      288.99997]]]
```

whats wrong here?

Comment: print both `points[0][0]` and `points[0][2]`. show us the output.

Comment: The points for `cv2.rectangle` should be tuple not NumPy array. Try `cv2.rectangle(tuple(self.img,points[0][0]), tuple(points[0][2]) ,color,thickness)` or `cv2.rectangle(tuple(self.img,points[0][0].astype(np.int32)), tuple(points[0][2].astype(np.int32)) ,color,thickness)`

Answer (score 1):

Given in your post that `print(points[0][0])` outputs `[ 40.       40.     ]` and `print(points[0][2])` outputs `[288.99997 288.99997]`, simply replace:

```
cv2.rectangle(self.img, points[0][0], points[0][2], color, thickness)
```

with:

```
pt1 = int(points[0][0][0]), int(points[0][0][1])
pt2 = int(points[0][2][0]), int(points[0][2][1])
cv2.rectangle(self.img, pt1, pt2, color, thickness)
```